# why I can't access to es8

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I pull elasticsearch:8.0.0 at powershell and start es8, and the app is running,I ENSURE this by seeing logs and docker desktop, but this can't be Accessed by browers[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvfxs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyXJg.png)

Comment: and i run es8's command is: docker run -dp  docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m"  --name es8 fef75

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch doesn't have a web interface built in. You need something like [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/kibana/) for that.